# c# sending json to website every 3 minutes issues

Tags: c#, http, rest

I have a windows app that sends a json to a website every 3 minutes. But I am not getting through to the web and I am not catching any exceptions which is strange. How it works.

Timer set to go off every 3min(180000milisecs)

```
timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(180000);
timer1.Elapsed += new  System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(onTimerEvent);
timer1.Start();
```

The timer calls a backround worker to run the update

```
    //run the worker job every 3 minutes
    private void onTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minerQuery.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

The worker calls the function to gather the data and then send the json

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string user_worker = textBox2.Text.Trim().ToLower() + ":" + textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        bool logging = false;
        if (this.radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            logging = true;
        }
        WorkerUpdate workerUpdate = new WorkerUpdate();
        workerUpdate.update(user_worker, logging);
    }
```

Once the function gathers the data in sends the request using this function

```
   static void HttpPutRequest(string Json, bool logging)
    {
        try{
            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https:/blah/here/update");
            Request.ContentType = "application/json";
            Request.Method = "PUT";
            Request.Timeout = 120000; //not sure if correct

              Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
              byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json);
              Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
              dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
              dataStream.Close();
              HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse(); 
              Stream RdataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
              StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(RdataStream);
              if (logging)
              {
                  Logger("Sending JSON: " + Json);
                  Logger("To URL: " + Request.ToString());
                  Logger("Status: " + ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                  Logger("Response: " + reader.ReadToEnd());
              }
              reader.Close();
              RdataStream.Close();
              response.Close();
          }
          catch (WebException we)
          {
              if (logging)
              {
                  Logger("Web Expection Catch: " + we.ToString());
                  WebExceptionStatus status = we.Status;
                  if (status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                  {
                      HttpWebResponse http = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
                      Logger("The Server returned protocal Error: " + (int)http.StatusCode + " - " + http.StatusCode);
                  }
              }
          }
    }
```

When I run my program it works and I see logging for other events. But when it comes to the http put request none of the logging in this code is every printed onto the screen. So I know something is going wrong. I put this code together from the MSDN examples which aren't the best.

Where I think the problem may be

1. Not sure if running this function under a timer event and a background worker is suppressing my expections?
2. Code to send http is not correct

HttpPutRequest is called here

```
              this.wun = user_worker;
              this.a = Convert.ToInt32(FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Accepted"), US);
              this.r = Convert.ToInt32(FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Rejected"), US);
              this.he = Convert.ToInt32(FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Hardware Errors"), US);
              this.gs = gpuList.ToArray();
              //create JSON from the workerUpdate object
              string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
              //send to website
              HttpPutRequest(JSON, logging);
```

### **Update**

Running the code in debug mode I found this exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
```

from this line of code

```
 Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
```

Comment: where is `HttpPutRequest` called?

Comment: oops sorry. ill update original post

Comment: Is the logging code updating the UI on the UI thread or the background thread?

Comment: it actually logs to a file and is all handled by the background thread. I really think the error is because my exceptions are being suppressed. Still not sure why the http code doesn't work.

Comment: Trying taking out the `try`/`catch` and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InvalidOperationException` is caused by calling `GetRequestStream()` before setting `ContentLength`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx

> ContentLength: InvalidOperationException is thrown if the request has
>   been started by calling the GetRequestStream, BeginGetRequestStream,
>   GetResponse, or BeginGetResponse method.

Try:

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json);
 Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
 Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
```

---

### Edit:

As for the Logging issue is could be because you are accessing UI controls in the BackgroundWorkers thread. and because you are only catching WebExceptions the error will not be logged.

Try adding all exceptions also in your try catch to be sure

Example:

```
  try
  {
      // all my cool logic
  }
  catch (WebException we)
  {
     // log WebException 
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // log other exceptions
  }
```

Comment: That fixed that error. My question now is why aren't these exceptions being logged? what is suppressing them?

Comment: Because you are only catching `WebException` not all `Exception`, I have added update to my answer to help catch other exceptions other than WebExceptions